# Derived set of subset $A$ of metric space $(X,d)$ is a closed set

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I have to prove that derived set of subset $A$ of metric space $(X,d)$ is a closed set.
And here is my attempt: it is sufficient to prove $\overline{A^{'}}=A^{'}$, and it is equivalent to prove $(A^{'})^{'}\subset A^{'}$.Suppose $A$ is infinite. (if $A$ is finite, $A^{'}$ is empty, it's closed. )So,$\forall x\in A^{'}, \exists  p_n\in A^{'}$ s.t. $p_n\rightarrow x$. If $A^{'}$ is finite, it is closed. If $A^{'}$ is infinite, we have $\forall y\in (A^{'})^{'}, \exists  x_n\in A^{'}$ s.t. $x_n\rightarrow y$.Now, I need to prove $\forall y\in (A^{'})^{'} \exists p_n\in A$ s.t. $p_n\rightarrow y$, which means every point of $(A^{'})^{'}$ is a limit point of $A$, i.e. $(A^{'})^{'}\subset A^{'}$. Fix $y\in(A^{'})^{'}$, then we have $x_n(\in A^{'})\rightarrow y$, and for each $x_n$, we have $p_n^m(\in A)\rightarrow x_n$, for each n, there exists $p_n^k$ s.t. $d(p_n^k,x_n)<\frac{1}{n}$, let $b_n=p_n^k$, then we have $b_n\rightarrow y$, and $y$ is arbitrary, thus $(A^{'})^{'}\subset A^{'}$.
I have 3 questions.

1.Is my proof correct?

2.If my proof is correct, can we use this method to prove the same property in Hausdorff space, we don't have something like "distance" in Hausdorff space, so I don't know how to select an element from $p_n^m$.

3.In my attempt, I find a subsequence $p_1^{k(1)},p_2^{k(2)}...$.And we can do the same thing in $\mathbb{R}$. If we have countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$, $A_{1}, A_{2},...,A_{n}...$, and for each $n$, $A_{n}$ is countable too, in other words, it is sequence, denoted as $A_{n}=\{a_{n1},a_{n2},a_{n3}...a_{nm}...\}$, suppose for each n, the sequence $a_{nm}$ is converge to $b_n$, now we have sequence $b_n$, and suppose $b_n$ is converge to $y$, like we did above, we can select $c_1\in A_1,c_2\in A_2...c_n\in A_n...$, then sequence $c_n$ is converge to $y$. We know the countable union of countable set is also countable, in this sense, $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$ is also a sequence $T_n$, so we can say there is a subsequence of $T_n$ converge to $y$. Is it true for sequence $T_n$? I guess it is related to the arrangement of $T_n$, for the arrangement of the set of rational numbers, it's false, however, I just know one arrangement of the countable union of countable set, it is the same as set of rational numbers. Do we have any other arrangement of these two sets? Especially, do we have a special arrangement makes proposition always true? Thanks!

Comment: What is the operation taking $A$ to $A'$?

Comment: $A^{'}$ is derived set of $A$

Comment: What does that mean in this context? Is this the Cantor-Bendixson 'core', so repeatedly removing all isolated points?

Comment: The derived set of a subset $A$ of a topological space is the set of all limit points of $A$ .  And $\overline{A^{'}}$ is closure of $A^{'}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your proof seems correct, although I think it would be cleaner if you didn't employ the second derivative, but rather assumed that there is a sequence $(a_n)\subset A'$ converging to some $a$ and then constructed the approximating sequence from $A$.
2. In general topological spaces characterizations of notions via sequences may no longer be true, vaguely speaking, because the family of neighborhoods may be too large. Therefore, I will use the general definition: $A'$ is the set of $a\in X$ such that every neighborhood of $a$ contains a point from $A\setminus\{a\}$. First, note that $A'\subseteq \overline{A}$ (to see that, note that any point $x\notin \overline{A}$ has a neighborhood not intersecting with $A$). Even more so, if $a$ is an isolated point of $A$, then $\overline{A} = \overline{A\setminus \{a\}}\cup \{a\}$, so that $A'\subseteq\overline{A\setminus \{a\}}$ (here, separation axioms are tacitly used).
   Assume that $a\notin A'$. Then there is a neighborhood $U$ of $a$ which does not contain any point of $A\setminus \{a\}$. This implies that $\overline{A\setminus \{a\}}\subseteq X\setminus U$, hence also $A'\subseteq X\setminus U$. Since the closure is the smallest closed set containng $A'$, this means that $\overline{A'}\subseteq X\setminus U$, hence $a\notin \overline{A'}$.
3. I'm not sure exactly what you are asking here. Do you mean that you want to enumerate any sequence of sequences in the way that it converges to the same limit as the subsequence chosen by the diagonal argument? Then the answer is no. If you take all the sequences to be $(1,0,0,\ldots)$, then all of them converge to $0$, but the whole collection of numbers contains infinitely many $1$'s. No matter how you rearrange them, there will always be a divergent subsequence.

Comment: About question 3, since $T_n$ is countable, intuitively and not rigorously, it seems like this $a_{11},a_{12}…a_{1m}…a_{21},a_{22}…a_{2m}…$, in this sense, it seems converge to $y$. However, you construct a counterexample. Thank you very much! And I find many other arrangement of $\mathbb{Q}$. I have no problem now. Thank you for your great answer!